# How to proxy all traffic except local traffic and ssh to another server?

Tags: iptables, proxy

I have an application that connects a local database on the loopback address. I would like to send all the traffic of this application to another server to hide it's IP. 
The first solution I tried is creating a SOCKS proxy by : 
`ssh -D -f -N  8080 me@98.25.2.181` 
and set the localnet parameter in the proxychains config file to avoid sending local traffic to the proxy server. But when I run my application with proxychains, it works for a couple of hours and then it stops working with 'init DLL' error. I found that proxychains is not a robust solution for my case.
Then I opted to look for a solution based on IPtables but could not find any step by step guide. Can you please give me some pointers? I'm really stuck on it. Thanks.